# Why do we use GraphQL with Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql, schema

I'm currently confused on why we create two same schemas, one for mongoose and other for GraphQL when developing the backend of a web app.

why can't we just use one of these APIs?

Why do we use both and what is the purpose for both?

Answer (score 1):

The **combination** of GraphQL and Mongoose *serves as a great tool for digital representation and manipulation*.
Though GraphQL and mongoose are different from one another as *Mongoose provides an specific object model* to change the way of communication with the MongoDB database while *GraphQL is a generic method changing the communication with server*.
You can also consider GraphQL and Mongoose as **2-separate layers** in your server.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is for communication between client and server. You have a scema there to define how this communication should look like. (e.g. every time you send information about a user to the client, you can send the user id, the username and the email and the biography. The client can then choose which of these information it needs)

Mongoose allows you to edit your MongoDB from the server. The mongoose scemas define how the data in the database should be structured.